# How do I get actual values from a Jacobian matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, vector-calculus, coordinate-transformation

I have a Jacobian function:

```
D[{Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]}, {{x, y}}]
```

It gives me a matrix with the formulas I need for my transposition matrix:

```
{{x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {-(y/(x^2 + y^2)), x/(x^2 + y^2)}}
```

How do I turn this into a formula that will give me values (the basis vectors) at a given value of $r$ and $\theta$?  (e.g. `f[{0.3,0.5}] = {{0.514496, 0.857493}, {-1.47059, 0.882353}}`)

Comment: As an aside: `CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Polar", "MappingJacobian"]` returns a pure function you can evaluate on vector arguments.

Comment: This is a teach-a-man-to-fish kind of question.  But thanks for the fish!

Comment: Yes, that's why it's a comment and not an answer. ;)

Comment: See, that's funny because that was the last thing the dolphins said before they left Earth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x0_, y0_] := D[{Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]}, {{x, y}}] /. {x -> x0, y -> y0}

f[0.3, 0.5] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

I would caution you *against* using `MatrixForm` in the definition, as that would leave you with results that cannot be easily used in further computation.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like

```
f[{r_, θ_}] := 
 Module[{M = D[{Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]}, {{x, y}}]}, 
  Block[{x = r Cos[θ], y = r Sin[θ]}, M]]
```

I wouldn't be surprised if this has a slightly simpler formulation.  The symbolic result agrees with what I expect:

```
Assuming[r > 0, Simplify[f[{r, θ}]]]
(* {{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {-(Sin[θ]/r), Cos[θ]/r}} *)
```

Numerically, it doesn't agree with your expectation.

```
f[{0.3, 0.5}]
(* {{0.877583, 0.479426}, {-1.59809, 2.92528}} *)
```

I might have misunderstood...